# How to fix the Duplicate class when using a Unity Project with admob as a module or library?

Tags: android, admob

How to fix the Duplicate class when using a Unity Project with admob as a module or library in a native android project?

I'm having this error when building a project in android studio.

Removing the duplicate class in the exported Unity Project would give an error when the admob is called. Removing the duplicate class in the Native android would also give an error.

```
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnimRes found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnimatorRes found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnyRes found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnyThread found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.ArrayRes found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AttrRes found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.BinderThread found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.BoolRes found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.CallSuper found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.CheckResult found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.ColorInt found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.ColorLong found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.ColorRes found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.DimenRes found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.Dimension found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.DrawableRes found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.FloatRange found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.FontRes found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.FractionRes found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.GuardedBy found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.HalfFloat found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.IdRes found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.IntDef found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.IntRange found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.IntegerRes found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.InterpolatorRes found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.Keep found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.LayoutRes found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.LongDef found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.MainThread found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.MenuRes found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.NavigationRes found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.NonNull found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.Nullable found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.PluralsRes found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.Px found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.RawRes found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.RequiresApi found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.RequiresFeature found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.RequiresPermission found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.RequiresPermission$Read found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.RequiresPermission$Write found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.RestrictTo found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.RestrictTo$Scope found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.Size found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.StringDef found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.StringRes found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.StyleRes found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.StyleableRes found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.TransitionRes found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.UiThread found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.VisibleForTesting found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.WorkerThread found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.XmlRes found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.arch.core.internal.FastSafeIterableMap found in modules androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar) and core-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap found in modules androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar) and core-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap$AscendingIterator found in modules androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar) and core-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap$DescendingIterator found in modules androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar) and core-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap$Entry found in modules androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar) and core-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap$IteratorWithAdditions found in modules androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar) and core-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap$ListIterator found in modules androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar) and core-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap$SupportRemove found in modules androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar) and core-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.arch.core.util.Function found in modules androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.arch.core.core-common-2.0.0.jar) and core-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.collection.ArrayMap found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.collection.ArrayMap$1 found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.collection.ArraySet found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.collection.ArraySet$1 found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.collection.CircularArray found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.collection.CircularIntArray found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.collection.ContainerHelpers found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.collection.LongSparseArray found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.collection.LruCache found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.collection.MapCollections found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.collection.MapCollections$ArrayIterator found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.collection.MapCollections$EntrySet found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.collection.MapCollections$KeySet found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.collection.MapCollections$MapIterator found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.collection.MapCollections$ValuesCollection found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.collection.SimpleArrayMap found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.collection.SparseArrayCompat found in modules androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection.collection-1.0.0.jar) and collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache found in modules androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar) and lifecycle-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache$CallbackInfo found in modules androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar) and lifecycle-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache$MethodReference found in modules androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar) and lifecycle-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.CompositeGeneratedAdaptersObserver found in modules androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar) and lifecycle-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.FullLifecycleObserver found in modules androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar) and lifecycle-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.FullLifecycleObserverAdapter found in modules androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar) and lifecycle-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.FullLifecycleObserverAdapter$1 found in modules androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar) and lifecycle-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.GeneratedAdapter found in modules androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar) and lifecycle-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.GenericLifecycleObserver found in modules androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar) and lifecycle-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle found in modules androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar) and lifecycle-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle$Event found in modules androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar) and lifecycle-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle$State found in modules androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar) and lifecycle-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver found in modules androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar) and lifecycle-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner found in modules androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar) and lifecycle-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycling found in modules androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar) and lifecycle-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.MethodCallsLogger found in modules androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar) and lifecycle-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent found in modules androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar) and lifecycle-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ReflectiveGenericLifecycleObserver found in modules androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar) and lifecycle-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.SingleGeneratedAdapterObserver found in modules androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common-2.0.0.jar) and lifecycle-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0)
```